# import "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer" is a program, not an importable package

Tags: go

I encountered the following error when compiling my app, which imports the package `github.com/Microsoft/go-winio`. The error is from that package. What could be wrong?

```
..\..\GoLang\GOPATH\pkg\mod\github.com\!microsoft\go-winio@v0.6.0\tools.go:5:8: import "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer" is a program, not an importable package
```

Answer (score 2):

The content of [tools.go @v0.6.0](https://github.com/microsoft/go-winio/blob/v0.6.0/tools.go) is:

```golang
//go:build tools

package winio

import _ "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer"
```

The purpose of this file is to version `stringer` in go.mod and allow
`go generate ./...` to be run without needing a `go get` call. See [How can I track tool dependencies for a module?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module) for more details.

In a normal build, this file will be excluded thanks to `//go:build tools`.

There are two possible reasons that result in this error.

##### 1. Your app is built with the `tools` tag

It's most likely that you happen to build your app with the `tools` tag. If this is your case, please choose another tag for your app.

I see the same error message with the following demo:

```
$ go run --tags tools main.go
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/!microsoft/go-winio@v0.6.0/tools.go:5:8: import "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer" is a program, not an importable package
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    winio "github.com/Microsoft/go-winio"
)

func main() {
    p, _ := winio.DecodeExtendedAttributes([]byte{})
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

##### 2. Your Go is too old

Another possible reason is that your Go is too old (1.15 or older) and it does not recognize `//go:build`. Please upgrade Go to 1.17 or newer.

```
$ go1.16 run main.go
main.go:6:2: //go:build comment without // +build comment
$ go1.15 run main.go
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/!microsoft/go-winio@v0.6.0/tools.go:5:8: import "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer" is a program, not an importable package
```